# Ho to add "Create Slider" option to default "Add Media" popup?

Tags: images, shortcode, uploads, media, gallery

What are the steps to create a custom "Create Slider" option in the default "Add Media" popup (the one used to insert images and gallery into editor)? The "Create Gallery" item should be below "Create Gallery" item. It should allow to select multiple images and insert a shortcode with images IDs similar to gallery shortcode.

[image]